# Can call function twice?

Tags: php

Whenever I run this code I get a:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare compare_distance()

The temporary solution appears to have been to duplicate `findNearestLocation()` and give it a different name, so instead of calling `findNearestLocation()` twice I call `findNearestLocation1()` and `findNearestLocation2()`.

I've tried unsetting the variables in the foreach loop but I can't quite figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: Could you add the error you are getting to your question, please?

Comment: It isn't obvious from your description just what you are talking about.  (You can't, for example, *define* a function twice.) You can, of course, *call* it as many times as you like.

Comment: @PietervandenHam - I'm getting a 500 error via ajax in the console

Comment: @MikeRobinson - I think I've explained badly.. I've updated the code and the question to hopefully make it clearer what's going on.

Comment: You should check the Apache/Nginx error logs

Comment: @PietervandenHam - I didn't know I could do that. :) Turns out MAMP has that sitting just waiting for me.. that alone was worth asking the question, and thankyou!

That said, now that I know the issue is declaring a function inside of a function I'm still left wondering why that's a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, man )

Change:

```
function findNearestLocation($clientLocation) {

    global $depotLocations;
    $findDepot = $depotLocations;
    $count = 0;

    foreach ($findDepot as $row) {

        $currentDepot = array($row['location_latitude'], $row['location_longitude']);
        $findDepot[$count]['distance'] = distance($currentDepot,$clientLocation);
        $count ++;

    }    

    function compare_distance($a, $b) {
        if ($a['distance'] == $b['distance']) return 0;
        return ($a['distance'] < $b['distance']) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    usort($findDepot, 'compare_distance');

    return $findDepot[0];

}
```

To:

```
function compare_distance($a, $b) {
    if ($a['distance'] == $b['distance']) return 0;
    return ($a['distance'] < $b['distance']) ? -1 : 1;
}

function findNearestLocation($clientLocation) {

    global $depotLocations;
    $findDepot = $depotLocations;
    $count = 0;

    foreach ($findDepot as $row) {

        $currentDepot = array($row['location_latitude'], $row['location_longitude']);
        $findDepot[$count]['distance'] = distance($currentDepot,$clientLocation);
        $count ++;

    }    

    usort($findDepot, compare_distance);

    return $findDepot[0];

}
```

Or to (if you are using PHP7):

```
function findNearestLocation($clientLocation) {

    global $depotLocations;
    $findDepot = $depotLocations;
    $count = 0;

    foreach ($findDepot as $row) {

        $currentDepot = array($row['location_latitude'], $row['location_longitude']);
        $findDepot[$count]['distance'] = distance($currentDepot,$clientLocation);
        $count ++;

    }    

    usort(
        $findDepot, 
        function ($a, $b) {return $a['distance'] <=> $b['distance'];}
    );

    return $findDepot[0];

}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm not using PHP7 but that's a much more elegant way to do a usort. :)

Comment: No problem, take care )

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the relatively simple solution was to not declare a function inside of a function.. once I moved `compare_distance()` outside of the `findNearestLocation()` function it works perfectly.

So now I understand the what, but I don't really understand the why.. what's the issue being created by declaring a function inside of a function?

Apologies if this seems an obvious issue, I'm fairly new to PHP still.

```
<?php 


function findNearestLocation($clientLocation) {

global $depotLocations;
$findDepot = $depotLocations;
$count = 0;

    foreach ($findDepot as $row) {

        $currentDepot = array($row['location_latitude'], $row['location_longitude']);
        $findDepot[$count]['distance'] = distance($currentDepot,$clientLocation);
        $count ++;

    }    

    function compare_distance($a, $b) {
        if ($a['distance'] == $b['distance']) return 0;
        return ($a['distance'] < $b['distance']) ? -1 : 1;
    }

usort($findDepot, 'compare_distance1');

return $findDepot[0];

}

function distance($depot, $clientLocation) { // need to send two arrays with only longitude and latitude

list($lat1, $lon1) = $depot;
list($lat2, $lon2) = $clientLocation;

$theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
$dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
$dist = acos($dist);
$dist = rad2deg($dist);
$kilometres = $dist * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344;

return $kilometres;
}

// 4. ** These next two lines cause the error. If I comment out either of these lines, the code works fine and returns the expected result.

$finalPickup = findNearestLocation($pickupLocation);
$finalDropoff = findNearestLocation($dropoffLocation);

var_dump($finalPickup);
var_dump($finalDropoff);
?>
```

Source: [@John Detlefs](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38268122/3)

Comment: You can call any function many times, but you can declare it only once. When compare_distance declaration was in the findNearestLocation function, every time when you call findNearestLocation, PHP tries to declare compare_distance again.

Answer (score 0):

My general understanding of the PHP language is, *well, (shrug),* that it has never been that *sophisticated.* It really doesn't know about *"nested* functions." It really only has *two* scopes for variables. And, so on.

(But then again, its designers never really *set out to* create "the most-popular web programming language in the world!"  So it goes ...)

The initial compiler-error message: `cannot re-declare {foobar},` was your first indication that the language didn't "grok" what you were trying to do.